# Is it safe to enumerate through [NSOperationQueue operations]?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, fast-enumeration

Is it safe to enumerate, via fast enumeration, through `[NSOperationQueue operations]`? Like so:

```
for (NSOperation *op in [operationQueue operations]) {
    // Do something with op
}
```

Since operations are asynchronous and executed on another thread, `operations` could change at any time (including during the main thread's execution). Does fast enumeration protect against this, or should I `copy` (and `autorelease`) the operations array instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's only *un*safe if the queue mutates the array while you're enumerating it.

However:

> Returns a new array containing the operations currently in the queue.

The word “new” in [there](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/operations) suggests to me that the queue will do the copy and autorelease for you, so you can safely enumerate through the array.

Comment: Indeed, very nice catch. Thanks Peter.